# Find the name of the graphical display emacs is running on

Tags: init-file, frames, display, fullscreen

I run emacs using a server and multiple clients on both, the graphical display and the terminal.

To use the same configuration files for terminal and graphical display, I used [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16435/4025) solution.

The issue is, on starting a new emacs client, the `fullscreen` function gets called on all the already running clients too, and causes a very unwanted behaviour which sometimes throws up errors too.

The `display-graphic-p` function doc says,

> `(display-graphic-p &optional DISPLAY)`
>
> Return non-nil if DISPLAY is a graphic display. Graphical displays are
>   those which are capable of displaying several frames and several
>   different fonts at once.  This is true for displays that use a window
>   system such as X, and false for text-only terminals. DISPLAY can be a
>   display name, a frame, or nil (meaning the selected frame's display).

I think my issue can be resolved by specifically calling the fullscreen function on the selected frame's display. So, my question is, *how to obtain the name of the current display?*

Comment: I think you should call it without arguments, that way you check if the current (selected) frame is a tty or graphical.

Comment: Yes. I do that. But after checking that, I need to call some functions to modify the concerned frame (graphical or tty). To do that, I need to pass the DISPLAY variable, else it calls the functions on all the running frames.

Comment: Can you post a link to the `fullscreen` package that you use.

Comment: https://github.com/safiyat/emacs/blob/76d67f8ce849ab88787f4c861685affe4fc5544a/loadpaths/fullscreen.el

But now I started using emacs 24.5 (since yesterday). Will see how its inbuilt fullscreen behaves. :)

Comment: It seem to ask the window system to enter fullscreen mode by sending X11 events. Obviously, you can't control which frames should be affected. Try to simply do `(set-frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'fullscreen 'fullboth)` instead, when the current frame is graphical.

Comment: This works!!! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging into `get-device-terminal` it looks like it's the same as the `device` or `tty` frame property.

According to the documentation, it's the X11 display name `HOST.SERVER.SCREEN`. On MS-windows it's simply the string `"w32"`.

Comment: Looks like what I have been looking for. Running it in my case prints `#<terminal 1 on /dev/pts/9>`. Have to figure out how to use that info. :)

Answer (score 1):

For frames running on a graphic display, the name of the current display as a string is obtained with `(frame-parameter nil 'display)`, which returns the `display` property of the selected frame.